# How to set focus to a specific entry control when loading a View using MVVM and .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, mvvm, maui

I have a View with an entry control and two buttons in a .NET MAUI MVVM project.  When the View loads the entry control is not focused. How can I set the focus to the entry control without adding functions to the code behind?  I.e. the code behind for the ContentPage just links the ViewModel to the BindingContext.

As far as I am aware the form controls should not be accessed directly from the ViewModel, so is it possible to set the focus to the entry control by some other means when the form loads?

Comment: You won't get around adding ***some*** code in the code behind file. There's no way around that if you don't want to break MVVM. Therefore, I suggest to either call `Focus()` on the `Entry` in the `OnAppearing()` override or add a delegate to your ViewModel and set that from the code behind. The delegate could then be used to invoke `Focus()` without the ViewModel ever knowing what it called.

Answer (score 6):

The only way that I could get this to work was to put in that xaml for my intended control for focus:

```
Loaded="OnEntryLoaded"
```

And then in the code behind:

```
private void OnEntryLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Name.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We cannot set the Entry focus in ViewModel without any code in .cs as you mentioned in the question.

The easiest way is set the focus in OnAppearing method (allows users to customize behavior immediately prior to the Page becoming visible):

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!myentry.IsVisible)
        {              
            Task.Delay(10).Wait();
        }
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
        {
            myentry.Focus();
        });
    });
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it seems that the focus is being called before the page has been loaded, hence having no effect.  To get around this I have had to add a delay to give the view more time to load before setting the focus.  I.e. `await Task.Delay(500)`

Comment: That seems  because the main ui thread instead of the time delay. I have updated my answer and you could have a try.

Comment: Thanks for the update, unfortunately this didn't work for me so still having to use the `await Task.Delay(500)` method.

Comment: It work for me using the default template. Maybe your UI is much more complicated. Then I think that may because the entry was not visible when set it focus. However, delay 500 is too time-consuming. So i update my answer, have another try in order to reduce the waiting time.

Comment: I suspect that my UI is more complicated and probably takes a bit more time to load.  I tried your revised solution but it didn't seem to work as the control was visible immediately and never hit the Task.Delay section.  I have however made slight change that checks for `!myEntry.IsLoaded` instead of `!myentry.IsVisible` which seems to work!!  Thanks.